# Is it possible to set EditText only accept unicode characters in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-typeface

Is it possible to make an android `EditText` accept only unicode characters? If so, how?

Comment: you can have a check at each input to see if the char was unicode. If not, delete it

Answer (score 0):

Currently, unicode only is not a restriction option for the `EditText` component, but you can dynamically check every symbol to see if it falls into that category or not, and if not remove it.

Comment: is there any way to know input entered is unicode or not ?